# Lattice barchart has incorrect tick labels

Tags: r, lattice

I am trying to create a bar chart in lattice but the x-axis tick marks are not showing correctly:

```
dd <- data.frame(Year = 1990:1999, Count = 0:9)
barchart(Count ~ Year, data = dd, horizontal = FALSE)
```

[image]

The tick labels for the x-axis should be 1990, 1991, ... not 1, 2.

I do not want to convert year to a factor before plotting because I need to combine the barchart with an xyplot using `c.trellis( ..., x.same = TRUE)` in `latticeExtra`, which does not seem to work with `factor` axes.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a custom `axis` function:

```
barchart(Count ~ Year, data=dd, horizontal=FALSE,
         axis=function(side, ...) { 
           if (side=="bottom") 
             panel.axis(at=seq_along(dd$Year), label=dd$Year, outside=TRUE, rot=0, tck=0) 
           else axis.default(side, ...)
         })
```

[image: barchart with custom axis function]